# Implementation problems with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I am using multiple threads to upload files to the server. The Java Applet is responsible for displaying the UI. Initially I start 5 threads using ThreadPoolExecutor & assign 5 files to them . After each upload, I get a notification from the server. When a thread completes execution ,  another new thread is assigned with a file until all the files are uploaded to the server.

Basic code structure as follows:

i> a method startUpload() is being called from the Java Applet which is responsible for handling the upload functionality.

```
class Upload extends Runnable{


...............................
..............................

public void startUpload() {

............................... //other initialisations done

    int waitTime = 500;

    Random random = new Random();

    ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 50000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(300));

    while (it.hasNext()) {

                int time = random.nextInt(1000);
                waitTime += time;
                newFile = new File((String) it.next());

                executor.execute(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                       try{
                       Thread.sleep(wait);
                       }
                       catch(Exception e){
                        }
                        processFile1(newFile);
                    }
                });

            }
           try {
                Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                executor.shutdown();
                executor.awaitTermination(waitTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

    }
```

}

The problem I am facing currently.

i> The UI is only updating at the end when all the files are upload. In the intermediate stage the UI is in a hanged state. It seems like the EDT is going to a blocked state.

The same code for UI rendering was working fine when I was using Thread class , notify/ sleep to implement the same functionality . I changed the code to ThreadPoolExecutor since I saw in a no of blogs/articles that its a better way of implementing multithreading from Java ver 5.0.

ii> Another thing which I noticed with the ThreadPoolExecutor , when I am uploading multiple files with size 1KB (for testing purpose) , if I remove all the wait() from the above code , the following line assigns a new file but the the same file is always being uploaded everytime by the multiple threads.

newFile = new File((String) it.next());

But on adding sleep() withing the run() , the multiple threads upload different files to the server.

Is there any implementation issue with the above code ?

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: `newFile` is a (static?) field instead of a local variable.

What you want is to make sure that the local capture of `newFile` is different each loop. As such, it should look more like:

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
  final File newFile = new File((String) it.next());
  executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      processFile1(newFile); // Local only to this iteration of the loop.
    }
  }
}
```

Your code is all wrapped in a `Runnable` instance. Can you let us know what Thread this is called from? If it's on the EDT then that would explain why the UI locks up.

A small issue is the lack of generics on your iterator. In theory, you should be iterating over a collection of Strings:

```
Collection<String> listOfFiles = ...

Iterator<String> it = listOfFiles.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()) { 
  String filename = it.next(); // No cast necessary
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The UI is hanging because you are blocking the EDT thread. This code is the culprit:

```
   try {
        Thread.sleep(waitTime);
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(waitTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

The idea of an `ExecutorService` is that you create it one time during initialization and never shut it down until the program is ready to exit. An idiom for this might be:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
});
```

As @Bringer128 mentioned, the second problem is caused by the fact that you are changing the value of a static or member variable and not assigning the `File` reference to a new location. If the code were correct, we would expect to see the `newFile` declared as `final File newFile` because non-final local variables may not be referenced in an inner-class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I changed the File to final & its a local variable currently . The problem I am getting is in some cases(once out of 3 times) the two threads are trying to upload the same file , the problem is basically thread synchronisation . From the server logs , I came to know that the two threads are trying to upload the same file , so its a duplicate request . Any suggestions on that ?

Comment: @chiranjib Try out the change I suggested. If `newFile` is a local variable as in my code then the executor will get the right value. You can't know when an executor will access `newFile` otherwise, so it could get the same or a different file depending on when the main thread updates it.